# MySQL - Add word to the end of a text column

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, insert

I need to add word 'example' to the end of a text column `keywords`.

**If the column already contains some text, added word will be separated by a space**:

```
Column `keywords` = '';
Add word 'example'
Result `keywords` = 'example'
```

**BUT**

```
Column `keywords` = 'Some text'
Add word 'example'
Result `keywords` = 'Some text example'
```

Comment: And what does your UPDATE statement look like so far?  Have you looked into the CASE clause at all?  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
UPDATE table
SET keyword=(
    CASE WHEN keyword=''
        THEN 'example'
        ELSE concat(keyword,' example')
    END
);
```

Comment: It is not correct. If the column does not contain any text, the result will be ' example'.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
UPDATE table SET `keyword` = CONCAT_WS(' ','your text',`keyword`)
```

[`Reference`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

Comment: If the column does not contain any text, the result will be ' example'.

Comment: @kor your question is not clear yet. you just want to display or save the data?

Comment: This works like a charm, but for someone who is learning, make sure you specify which row you are affecting by using UPDATE `table` SET `keyword` = CONCAT_WS(' ', 'your text', `keyword`) WHERE id = 1; if you don't will update and concatenate all values for column keyword with the new value.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
UPDATE table 
   SET `keyword` = CONCAT(`keyword`, ' ', 'example')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach that some may prefer:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `keywords` = TRIM(CONCAT(`keywords`, ' ', 'example'))
```

This **will not** leave a leading space if the field is empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
select concat(keyword,' example') from tbl ;
```

EDITED:
To update,use below:

```
UPDATE table
SET keyword =  CASE keyword WHEN '' THEN 'example' ELSE concat(keyword,' example') END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Select CONCAT(keywords,'example') from myTable